# How to download file from website to S3 bucket without having to download to local machine

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to download a dataset from a website. However all the files I want to download add up to about 100 gb which I don't want to download to my local machine, then upload to s3. Is there a way to download directly to an s3 bucket? Or do you have to use ec2, and if so could somebody give brief instructions on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: The EC2 approach is probably your best bet. There's no way to trigger an S3-initiated fetch like this; you could probably figure out a way to do it via Lambda, but EC2's likely to be faster.

Comment: @ceejayoz Could you give some brief instructions on how to do this? Should I open the ec2 instance on a remote desktop to download the files from the website, then upload to s3?

Comment: @awrd2019 Do you have access to the server that is running the website? How do you know what file are on the server? (Is it providing a list of them?)

Comment: Hi, Can you edit the tags to indicate the programming language? Ta

Answer (score 0):

S3's [`put_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) method supports a Body parameter for Bytes (or file):

Python example:

```
response = client.put_object(
    Body=b'bytes'|file,
    Bucket='string',
    Key='string',
)
```

So if you download a webpage, using Python you'd use the `requests.Get()` method or .Net you use either `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` and then upload the file as a byte array so you never need to save it locally. It can all be done in memory.

> Or do you have to use ec2

An Ec2 is just a VM in the cloud, you can programatically do this task (download 100gb to S3) from your Desktop PC/Laptop. Simply open an Command Window or a Terminal and type:

```
AWS Configure
```

Put in an IAM users creds and use the aws cli or use an AWS SDK like the python example above. You can give the S3 Bucket a Policy Document that will allow access to the IAM user. This will download everything to your local machine.

If you want to run this on an EC2 and avoid downloading everything to your local PC modify the role assigned to the EC2 and give it Put privileges to S3. This will be the easiest and most secure. If you use the in-memory and bytes approach it will download all the data but it wont save it to disk.